# Foreach variable to update database wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, foreach

How to give a variable to update wordpress database?

If instead of a variable, I give number is ok, I think this is a mistake.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->teams = $wpdb->prefix.'teams';
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->teams WHERE moder = 'nie'" );

    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){
        echo "<form method='post'><table><tr>";
        echo "<td>".$retrieved_data->id."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$retrieved_data->nazwa."<input type='hidden' name='id'>".$retrieved_data->id."</input><input type='submit' value='OK' /></td>";
        echo "</tr></table></form>";
    }

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    settype($id, 'int');
    $wpdb->update( 'teams', array( 'moder' => 'tak' ), array( 'id' => $id ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! done :)
thx :)
final code

```
  global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "teams";
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE moder = 'nie'" );

foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {
    echo "<form method='post'><table><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$retrieved_data->id."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$retrieved_data->nazwa."<input type='text' name='id' value='$retrieved_data->id' /><input type='submit' name='test' value='OK' /></td>";
    echo "</tr></table></form>";
}

print_r($_POST);
$id = $_POST['id'];
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "teams";
$wpdb->update( $table, array( 'moder' => 'tak' ), array( 'id' => $id ));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is basically wrong. You show the form, then you just update your table with no values. After you submit the form, then update the table. But if anybody load the page, and do not submit the form, then you will update again with 0.

I think, you will also need to validate the id field.

Try to this on this way:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->teams = $wpdb->prefix . 'teams';

//Do this before any output in the buffer...

//Check is there is a $_POST["id"]. And move this update block to the top of your file
if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    settype($id, 'int');
    $wpdb->update('teams', array('moder' => 'tak'), array('id' => $id));
    //redirect the user to somewhere
    header ("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
}


$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->teams WHERE moder = 'nie'");

foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {
    echo "<form method='post'><table><tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $retrieved_data->id . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $retrieved_data->nazwa . "<input type='hidden' name='id'>" . $retrieved_data->id . "</input><input type='submit' value='OK' /></td>";
    echo "</tr></table></form>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\mtb\wp-content\themes\seebcioo\header.php:16) in C:\wamp\www\mtb\wp-content\themes\seebcioo\panel-adm-teams.php on line 17"

line 17: header ("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);